# DB2 query Unknown column name ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: sql, db2

A co-worker has baffled us all with a query that is failing for reasons we can't divine. I can confirm that `ENOTE.EN_FILTER_VALUE_L.FILTER_VALUE_DECODE` does exist in the database.  At least three people have stared at it trying to find misspellings.

The Query:

```
SELECT sub.ID, sub.USER_ID, sub.EN_TYPE_CODE, 
typ.EN_TYPE_DESC, typ.APPL_CD, filterval.FILTER_VALUE_DECODE AGENCY_TYPE, 
sub.EN_TYPE_CODE CONCAT ' | ' CONCAT typ.EN_TYPE_DESC ENOTE_STRING, 
org1.ORG_LVL1_CD, org1.ORG_LVL1_DC,
org2.ORG_LVL2_CD, org2.ORG_LVL2_DC,
org3.ORG_LVL3_CD, org3.ORG_LVL3_DC, 
org4.ORG_LVL4_CD, org4.ORG_LVL4_DC 
FROM ENOTE.EN_SUBSCRIPTION_T sub 
LEFT JOIN ENOTE.EN_TYPE_L typ ON sub.EN_TYPE_CODE = typ.EN_TYPE_CODE 
LEFT JOIN ENOTE.EN_FILTER_OFFICE_T filteroffice ON sub.ID = filteroffice.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
LEFT JOIN UMC.ORG_LVL4_L org4 ON org4.ORG_LVL4_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL4_CODE
      AND org4.ORG_LVL3_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL3_CODE
      AND org4.ORG_LVL2_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL2_CODE 
      AND org4.ORG_LVL1_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL1_CODE 
      AND org4.STRUCTURE_CD = filteroffice.STRUCTURE_CODE 
LEFT JOIN UMC.ORG_LVL3_L org3 ON org3.ORG_LVL3_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL3_CODE 
      AND org3.ORG_LVL2_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL2_CODE 
      AND org3.ORG_LVL1_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL1_CODE 
      AND org3.STRUCTURE_CD = filteroffice.STRUCTURE_CODE 
LEFT JOIN UMC.ORG_LVL2_L org2 ON org2.ORG_LVL2_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL2_CODE 
      AND org2.ORG_LVL1_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL1_CODE
      AND org2.STRUCTURE_CD = filteroffice.STRUCTURE_CODE 
LEFT JOIN UMC.ORG_LVL1_L org1 ON org1.ORG_LVL1_CD = filteroffice.ORG_LVL1_CODE 
      AND org1.STRUCTURE_CD = filteroffice.STRUCTURE_CODE
LEFT JOIN ENOTE.EN_FILTER_VALUE_L filterval ON 
   (filteroffice.AGENCY_TYPE_CODE = filterval.FILTER_VALUE AND filterval.FILTER_NAME   = 'Agency Type')
```

The Exception:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: [jcc][10150][10300][4.3.111] Invalid
>   parameter: Unknown column name FILTER_VALUE_DECODE. ERRORCODE=-4460,
>   SQLSTATE=null

Comment: But wait!  It gets wierder.  It appears that this query WORKS on ONE of our co-worker's workstations.  Appears to be the same code base.  Our environments appear the same.  This behavior suggests some environment difference.  I should also mention that th query works when pasted into the DB2 Control Center.

Comment: I would check permissions on `ENOTE` -- the permissions for this table are probably different from other tables.

Comment: Good thought, but we all use the same user (an application user) in our development environments, and it works in one, but fails in another. Other SQL and HQL reference this table with no problems. And it now appears that at least one user, running the same SQL from the same code CAN run it successfully.  That user had a slightly different driver/data source config, but we changed one of our broken environments to use the same to no effect.  *whistles Twilight Zone Theme*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-asked this question here [db2jcc4.jar Invalid parameter: Unknown column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981711/db2jcc4-jar-invalid-parameter-unknown-column-name) and got the answer.

The combination of Hibernate 3.x and the JCC driver in DB2 9.5 and above have a spec level mismatch.  Upgrading to Hibernate 4.x will solve the issue, but if you can't do that in the short term setting a custom data source property of `useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=2` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Newer DB2 JDBC drivers exhibit different behaviour when returning column names using the "AS" clause.

Modify the query to use an expression in the column name:

**select  as MY_NAME from TABLE where ID=1**

For example, concatenate a blank with the column name:

**select COLUMN_NAME || '' as MY_NAME from TABLE where ID=1**

Answer (score 0):

Could this be an issue with length of the alias name?

I got this error, changed column from:

`... AS PREVIOUS_MONTH_REDEEMED_RESULTS ...`

TO

`... AS pmrr ...`

And it worked fine!

Comment: Perhaps in your case.  For us it was hibernate version (as described in my answer above)