# db2 Invalid parameter: Unknown column name SERVER_POOL_NAME . ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: jdbc, properties, db2, db2-luw

I am using SQL 'select' to access a db2 table  with schemaname.tablename as follows:

```
select 'colname' from schemaname.tablename
```

The tablename has 'colname' = SERVER_POOL_NAME  for sure . yet I get the following  error :
 "Invalid parameter: Unknown column name SERVER_POOL_NAME  . ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null"

I am using db2 v10.1 FP0  jdbc driver version  3.63.123.   JDBC 3.0 spec 
The application is run as db2 administrator and also Windows 2008 admin

I saw a discussion about this issue at : [db2jcc4.jar Invalid parameter: Unknown column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981711/db2jcc4-jar-invalid-parameter-unknown-column-name)

But i do not know where the connection parameter 'useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics should be set ( to value =2)

I saw the parameter  should appear in com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource ( see: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fimjcc_r0052607.html)

But i do not find this file on my DB2 installation . maybe it is packed in a .jar file

Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

[There is a link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvdsprp.html) on the page you're referring to, showing you the ways to set properties. Specifically, you can populate a `Properties` object with desired values and supply it to the `getConnection()` call:

```
String url = "jdbc:db2://host:50000/yourdb";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics", "2");
// set other required properties
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

Alternatively, you can embed property name/value pairs in the JDBC URL itself:

```
String url = "jdbc:db2://host:50000/yourdb:useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=2;";
// set other required properties
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Note that each name/value pair must be terminated by a semicolon, even the last one.