# Connect to DB2 error via JDBC when using connection string including user and password

Tags: jdbc, db2

I'm trying to connect DB2 via JDBC.

I can connect successfully through the following:

```java
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/SAMPLE", "db2admin", "xxxxxxx");
```

But I want to use the connection string including user and password.
So I refer to https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=cdsudidsdjs-url-format-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj-type-4-connectivity

However, I can not connect to DB2 in this way.

```java
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/SAMPLE:user=db2admin;password=xxxxxxx");
```

The error message:

```sh
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10165][10051][4.29.24] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/SAMPLE:user=db2admin;password=xA123456. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

This is my maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
    <version>11.5.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm very confused. Can anyone provide a clue?

Comment: I was missing a semicolon at the end of the connection string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [db2 Invalid parameter: Unknown column name SERVER\_POOL\_NAME . ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536945/db2-invalid-parameter-unknown-column-name-server-pool-name-errorcode-4460-s)