# Setting Hibernate 3 to use useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

We are using Hibernate 3 and DB2 running into the:

> Invalid parameter: Unknown column name FOO. ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null

problem which is a common problem I see when searching online.  Basically, we need to force Hibernate to retrieve columns by column name.  An example of a Stack Overflow question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981711/db2jcc4-jar-invalid-parameter-unknown-column-name)

If you read Mark Rotteveel's answer he suggests "set the `useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics` Connection or DataSource property to DB2BaseDataSource.NO (2)"

My question is, how do I this in Hibernate?  I cannot find an example of how to set a JDBC property such as this.  Does Hibernate have this property built in?

Answer (score 1):

The [manual clearly explains](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) how to set JDBC connection properties.

If you use `hibernate.properties` to configure Hibernate, you add

```
hibernate.connection.useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=2
```

to the file. If you use `hibernate.cfg.xml`, you add

```
<property name="connection.useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics">2</property>
```

to the `session-factory` element. You can also use `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setProperty()` method.

Finally, you can simply append the property to the JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:db2://hostname:port/database:useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=2;
```