# Xquery with JDBC -- Bad SQL grammar

Tags: spring, maven, jdbc, db2, xquery

I try to execute a SQL request (that contain a XMLQUERY statement) with JDBCtemplate. But each time I execute the request DB2 send me an error telling me "Bad SQL grammar". And there is not a lot of documentation for Xquery with JDBC.

This request aim to process a column of my DB2 database (that contain XML). It's important to add that I work in a big company and so I can't download all the dependencies I want and in the same way i'm not free with the tech I can use.
I tried to execute the request without XMLQUERY and it worked so the problem probably come from the communication between Xquery and JDBC.
+ the full request work when I execute her directly in squirel on my DB2 DB.

1: The SQL request:

```java
String sql = "select XMLQUERY (\n" +
                "'for $l in $t/Table/Ligne\n" +
                "let $a0 :=$l/@CD_TYP_REJ_REJET\n" +
                "where ($a0 != \"AS\")return $l'\n" +
                "passing val_cttab as \"t\")\n" +
                "from tptcttab\n" +
                "where cd_tab_atp_cttab = 'ACTREJ';\n";
```

2: The dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.24.92</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I expect a simple display of a XML format but I get this error ->

1: Short-Logs:

```
Wed Sep 11 10:13:17 CEST 2019

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select XMLQUERY ( 'for $l in $t/Table/Ligne let $a0 :=$l/@CD_TYP_REJ_REJET where ($a0 != "AS")return $l' passing val_cttab as "t") from tptcttab where cd_tab_atp_cttab = 'ACTREJ'; ]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=;;atp_cttab = 'ACTREJ';END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=4.19.49

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select XMLQUERY ( 'for $l in $t/Table/Ligne let $a0 :=$l/@CD_TYP_REJ_REJET where ($a0 != "AS")return $l' passing val_cttab as "t") from tptcttab where cd_tab_atp_cttab = 'ACTREJ'; ]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=;;atp_cttab = 'ACTREJ';END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=4.19.49
```

So here I am I don't have a clue on why it doesn't work with JDBC so if you guy have an Idea it could help me a lot thanx !

Comment: Need to see the SQL that actually arrives to Db2, because Db2 is rejecting the token `;;atp_cttab = 'ACTREJ'`. Why the double semi-colon ?  To see the raw SQL use either jdbc trace, or ask your DBA if you have one. Refer to Db2 docs for details of enabling jdbc trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-104 is

```
  SQL0104N  An unexpected token "<token>" was found following "<text>".
  Expected tokens may include: "<token-list>".
```

and it is complaining about `'ACTREJ';` so I would think it is the `;` at the end of your statement that you don't need.

Certainly this runs for me from the db2 clp and DataStudio

```
select XMLQUERY ('for $l in $t/Table/Ligne let $a0 :=$l/@CD_TYP_REJ_REJET where ($a0 != "AS")return $l' passing val_cttab as "t") from tptcttab where cd_tab_atp_cttab = 'ACTREJ'
```

although I do get no value back with your sample data

Comment: Ok so first thanks the semicolon was the reason of this SQL error. But now it seem that `passing val_cttab as \"t\")\n` generate another problem. val_cttab is not recognize in the full request but when I use a simple sql request like  `select val_cttab from tptcttab` it work perfectly. Here are the new error line : (SQL state [null]; error code [-4460]; [jcc][10150][10300][4.19.49] Paramètre non valide : Nom de colonne inconnu (invalid parameter : unknown column's name) VAL_CTTAB. ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException)

Comment: @CorentinRenard You must have a `val_cttab` column of type `XML` in your `tptcttab` table according to your query. Do you really have it? If so, then provide some its sample data contents and the result you want to get with your query.

Comment: if you have a new error, you should ask a new Stack Overflow question, and before you do that, try a search to see if anyone else has asked that question before. E.g. maybe this is a match for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981711/db2jcc4-jar-invalid-parameter-unknown-column-name  and/or https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-sql-query-select-gives-sql-errorcode-4460